# How to set this excel range as range ?(error occurs)

Tags: vba, excel

Basic Info:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String ' number to letter function 
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr
End Function

 'Worksheets ("button").cells(1,3).value   ' with value 12
    'Worksheets ("button").cells(2,3).value   ' with value 15
```

---

I want to use dim a range-mandayrng with the range L3: Q10
And sum the range- mandayrng .

```
Dim mandayrng as range

    mandayrng = Worksheets("manday").Range(cells(Col_Letter(Worksheets ("button").cells(2,3).value),3), cells(Col_Letter(Worksheets ("button").cells(2,3).value),10))'the range is L3: Q10
```

---

```
With Worksheets("report")
row = worksheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
For k = 6 To row
    Worksheets("report").Cells(i, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(mandayrng) 'sum with the range of mandayrng

    Next k
    End With
```

However the code here is not working .

How to fix ?

Comment: What do you mean with your code is not working? Please be more specific.

Comment: You need to watch this video [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Col_Letter`.  Cells take a letter or number for a .

[image]

A Range can take a string address starts with a column letter and is followed by the row index.  If Range has two parameters then the range extends from the first parameter to the second including all the cells in between.

[image]

These Examples all refer to "L3:Q10"

- `Range("L3:Q10")`
- `Range("$L$3:$Q$10")`
- `Range("L3", "Q10")`
- `Range("Q10", "L3")`
- `Range(Cells(3,"L"), Cells(10,"Q"))`
- `Range(Cells(3, 12), Cells(10, 17))`
- `Range(Cells(10,"Q"), Cells(3,"l"))`
- `Range(Cells(3, 17), Cells(10, 12))`
- `Range("L3", Cells(10, 12))`
- `Range(Cells(3, 17),  "Q10")`

A Range will not accept a single cell as an argument (e.g. `Range(Cells(1,1))` is invalid)

The ranges and it's Cells arguments must be on the same worksheet.

The code below will work if `Worksheets("manday")` is the ActiveWorksheet because if a range is not qualified it is automatically assume to be on the ActiveWorksheet.

`Worksheets("manday").Range(Cells(3,"L"), Cells(10,"Q"))`

Here is a workaround:

`Worksheets("manday").Range(Cells(3,"L").address, Cells(10,"Q").address)`

This is also valid

`Worksheets("manday").Range(Worksheets("manday").Cells(3,"L"), Worksheets("manday").Cells(10,"Q"))`

But I prefer this:

```
With Worksheets("manday")
    Set mandayrng = .Range(.Cells(3, FirstColumn), .Cells(10, LastColumn))

End With
```

---

```
Dim FirstColumn As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer

FirstColumn = Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 3).Value
LastColumn = Worksheets("button").Cells(2, 3).Value

With Worksheets("manday")
    Set mandayrng = .Range(.Cells(3, FirstColumn), .Cells(10, LastColumn))

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you always have to use the set command with a range, otherwise you get an object or block variable not defined error.

```
Dim mandayrng as range

   set mandayrng = Worksheets("manday").Range(cells(Col_Letter(Worksheets ("button").cells(2,3).value),3), cells(Col_Letter(Worksheets ("button").cells(2,3).value),10))'the range is L3: Q10
```

edit:  for the with section you dont have to specify worksheet:

```
With Worksheets("report")
    row = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For k = 6 To row
        .Cells(i, 6) = Application.WorksheetFunction.sum(mandayrng) 'sum with the range of mandayrng
    Next k
End With
```

finally, regarding the code below, you want to return an array from the function.  To do this make sure you have the brackets, as are necessary for an array:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String()
Dim vArr() as string
```

in other news if you put dim vArr im not sure what will happen, be specific and use 'as long/string etc'

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim mySum As Double

    With Worksheets("button")
        mySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("manday").Range(Cells(3, .Cells(1, 3).value), Cells(3, .Cells(2, 3).value)))
    End With
    With Worksheets("report")
        .Range("F6:F" & .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).value = mySum
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, should you want to use `Function Col_Letter()` then change it like follows:

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String ' number to letter function
    Col_Letter = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
End Function
```